# Como ejecutar dos acciones al mismo tiempo

Tags: php, mvc

Estoy tratando de ejecutar estas dos acciones al mismo tiempo pero solo hace la primera accion que encuentra, he buscado la forma pero aun no la encuentro: La primera genera un pdf que se descarga por si solo.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" action="index.php?action=printformulario">
```

La segunda se encarga de guardar el formulario o sea sus datos, tienen algun consejo?

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" action="index.php?action=addformulario">
```

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
            
            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                  <i class="fa fa-ticket"></i> Formulario
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body ">
      
                <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" action="http://localhost/mi-tienda/admin/core/modules/index/view/facturas/facturas/facturas.php">
                  <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" action="index.php?action=addfactura">
 <div class="form-group">
    <label  for="inputEmail1" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Nombre del Cliente</label>
    <div class="col-lg-10">
      <input type="text" name="nombre_cliente" required class="form-control"  id="inputEmail1" placeholder="Nombre del Cliente">
    </div>
  </div>
 <div class="form-group">
    <label  for="inputEmail1" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Apellido del Cliente</label>
    <div class="col-lg-10">
      <input type="text" name="apellidos_cliente" required class="form-control"  id="inputEmail1" placeholder="Apellido del Cliente">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-6">
    <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary" type="submit">GENERAR </button>
    </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4">
      <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default btn-block">Limpiar Campos</button>
      </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Lo más simple sería que **replantees tu lógica**. Si necesitas al mismo tiempo agregar e imprimir el formulario, entonces piensa en una acción `addAndPrint`, esa sería la única acción del actual formulario y en el backend podrías combinar el código que usas para agregar y para imprimir, suponiendo que en algunos escenarios esas acciones puedan invocarse separadamente. O sea, es más bien un problema de lógica o de organización de código.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Esta mal planteado tu código, no puedes anidar formularios.

Si debes ejecutar una acción basado en la selección del usuario, utiliza solo un destino en tu formulario, donde ejecutes una u otra acción en función del valor recibido de algún campo.

Por ejemplo puedes tener multiples input:submit segun el que preciones sera el que valor que recibas en backend

Si requieres ejecutar ambas acciones con dos destinos diferentes, opta por usar javascript por ejemplo

```
<form action="#" id="contact">
  <input type="text" id="first_name" placeholder="Nombre">
  <input type="text" id="last_name" placeholder="Apellido">
  <input type="text" id="email" placeholder="Email">
  <button value="">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

Y con javascript interceptas el submit y envias dos request

```
const contactForm = document.querySelector('#contact');

if(contactForm){
    contactForm.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    // fetch() // evento 1
    // fetch() // evento 2
  })
}
```